How to request an output from a usb device using usb library and node.js
I am creating an app to update the firmware on my usb device and need a way to check the progress on the update from the device's side. I am trying to figure out what exactly the output is so I can code everything correctly.
I have tried using the controlTransfer method, but that just outputs the device descriptors. The format of the output should either be a 1 for fail or 0 for pass. Is there a better method/function to use with this kind of request besides controlTransfer? It seems like that method just outputs the device itself.


function getFeedback() {
    return device.controlTransfer(0x80, request, value, 0, 1);
};
var deviceProgress = getFeedback();




I managed to figure this out using the callback of the control transfer function. device.controlTransfer(0x80, request, value, 0, 1, (err, data) { console.log(data) })
